# Visual Studio 2008 - Toolbar missing 'Release' / 'Debug' dropdown build configuration

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, configuration, toolbar

how to enable the dropdown that shows build mode 'release/debug' ?
I have set the 'show advanced build configuration' option. I added the 'configuration manager' to the build toolbar but in previous versions we could do this by using the drop-down control.

TIA

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the Solution Configurations option to the build toolbar, that should give you the dropdown.

Comment: BTW, in VS 2010, the "Solution Configurations" command is in category "Build" in the list of categories, when do "Add Command..."

Answer (score 25):

The easiest way to fix this is to reset your settings to the General or C# profile.

> Tools -> Import / Export Settings

The VB profile will hide this toolbar by default

Comment: This was not working for me, for Visual Studio 2010. Here was the solution: If you're using an Express version of VS, turn on the Expert Settings (Tools->Settings->Expert Settings). Then the solution here works.

Answer (score 15):

To add the Solution Configuration onto your Toolbar, try the following:

View|Toolbars|Customize, 
then select the Commands tab, 
select the Build category and 
drag the Solution Configuration and drop it onto your toolbar

Answer (score 4):

1. Before going to next steps, try the tip from the first response below. This should solve the problem in most cases. If not, continue with the following steps.
2. Go to menu Tools - Customize… (or right-click on any toolbar and Customize…)
3. Switch to Commands tab.
4. Select Build under Categories.
5. Select Solution Configurations under Commands.
6. Drag and drop it on the toolbar where you wish this drop down list to appear.

Hope Sure this will helps you.

Answer (score 2):

I too was facing this issue but I've found a solution:

`Tools->Import/Export settings` -> select the C# setting and General settings.

I am able to see the `Debug/Release` drop-down.

Answer (score 1):

To add the Solution Configuration onto your Toolbar, try the following:

View|Toolbars|Customize, then select the Commands tab, select the Build category and drag the Solution Configuration and drop it onto your toolbar

It's in Tools\Options\Projects and Solutions. Select the Show advanced build configurations checkbox and click OK.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the Expert Settings (Tools->Settings->Expert Settings) if using VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently programming in C++ with VS 2008 and had the problem of not being able to find the Configuration selection drop-down. The solution given by JayV worked for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you start a new web site by going to File > New  > New Web Site. When what you really want is File > New Project > Then in new window click ASP.Net website.